# Begin...End blocks in SQL Server: Is this code right?

Tags: sql-server, syntax

I just want to verify that I'm not missing something here... so bear with me.

I'm rewriting a lot of old stored procedures and keep seeing IF statements formatted similar to this:

```
begin
    if @someParameter <> 'ThisType'
    set @someCode = right(cast(@pYear as varchar(6)),2) + 'THIS'
end
```

So the Begin...End block just wraps (but does not effect) the IF statement, right? Is this some older syntax for IF or something?

The guy who wrote this didn't have a lot of SQL experience prior to this job; he worked mostly in VB (pre-.NET). Maybe this is syntax from some other language, so he accidentally wrote it this way (by habit)?

This is SQL Server 2005 (code was written on/for SQL Server 2000), btw

Like I said, I'm just trying to wrap my brain around this spaghetti. Any thoughts/comments/illuminating insights are welcome

Thanks

Comment: I'm still baffled how/why the code got written this way. Guess he just misunderstood the syntax originally, then kept doing it.

It's funny... I seem to remember the guy warning me that complicated IF statements are flaky in T-SQL. Can you guess why he might run into trouble? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In T-SQL Begin and END should wrap the contained statements of an IF (or other control structure) with multiple statements being executed (like a code block)

**Would Work**

```
if @someParameter <> 'ThisType'
    set @someCode = right(cast(@pYear as varchar(6)),2) + 'THIS'
```

**Would Also Work but not strictly necessary**

```
if @someParameter <> 'ThisType'
Begin
    set @someCode = right(cast(@pYear as varchar(6)),2) + 'THIS'
End
```

**Would work as expected**

```
if @someParameter <> 'ThisType'
Begin
    set @someCode = right(cast(@pYear as varchar(6)),2) + 'THIS'
    {...do other stuff}
End
```

**Would not work as expected** (if you expected the both statements to only execute if the IF condition is me)

```
if @someParameter <> 'ThisType'
    set @someCode = right(cast(@pYear as varchar(6)),2) + 'THIS'
    {...do other stuff}
```

**No semantic value**

```
Begin --without wrapping control structure
    {...stuff}
End
```

Answer (score 3):

Correct.  The begin...end block in your example encapsulates the IF statement, but does not affect it.  Though the guilty programmer probably should have done

```
BEGIN
  if ... BEGIN
    set @somecode...
  END
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can safely change it to:

```
if @someParameter <> 'ThisType'
begin
    set @someCode = right(cast(@pYear as varchar(6)),2) + 'THIS'
end
```

*begin..end* is still extra, but the code is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what's before that.  The code you've posted is the same as

```
if @someParameter <> 'ThisType'
set @someCode = right(cast(@pYear as varchar(6)),2) + 'THIS'
```

There could be a statement before the if that requires a begin/end block though.

Comment: Good thought, but nothing relevent before the BEGIN. It's a discreet block

Comment: oops... make that "discrete"