# SQL Server BEGIN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

First, I have seen this post [SO on the Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507677/begin-end-blocks-in-sql-server-is-this-code-right) but I never knew when you really need and don't need `BEGIN END`.

Take this example

```
  If (@pInsLName <> 'null')
    Select @pInsLNameact = Cast (@pInsLName As VarChar(60)) 
  Else
    Select @pInsLNameact = Null
```

Or

```
  If (@pInsLName <> 'null')
    Begin
      Select @pInsLNameact = Cast (@pInsLName As VarChar(60))    
    End
  Else
    Begin
      Select @pInsLNameact = Null
    End
```

In the example above is there any benefit to using versus not using BEGIN and END statements?

Comment: `BEGIN` and `END` wrap *blocks* of code. The top snippet in your post is acceptable because the statements within your `IF` and `ELSE` only contain a single line, however as soon as you have two or more, you'll need `BEGIN...END`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question/answer you linked to explains it well enough. There is also [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180279/when-do-i-need-to-use-begin-end-blocks-and-the-go-keyword-in-sql-server). Basically `BEGIN` and `END` signify a block of statements. In the case of an `IF` it groups the statements together so that they all execute as part of the condition defined in the `IF` or `ELSE` portions of the statement.

Comment: the post you shared finally got it to click in my thick head. From the post "BEGIN and END are just like { and } in C/++/#, Java, etc."  I needed the comment about the { }.

Answer (score 1):

I like the example below from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190487.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

If you did not include the `BEGIN` and `END` both of the `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` statements and both of the `PRINT` statements would execute.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
BEGIN TRANSACTION;  
GO  
IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0  
BEGIN  
    SELECT FirstName, MiddleName   
    FROM Person.Person WHERE LastName = 'Adams';  
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
    PRINT N'Rolling back the transaction two times would cause an error.';  
END;  
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
PRINT N'Rolled back the transaction.';  
GO  
/*  
Rolled back the transaction.  
*/
```

Comment: MSDN, truly poor example, since there is nothing in the code to rollback

Comment: A transaction is still created.